# Generate a page from a custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm rephrasing my question about creating pages using a Wordpress plugin. Hopefully I do a better job.

Most WP plugins instruct the the use to add a page manually and then add a shortcode. This is a very flexible approach in general. BUT, what I'm wondering, is if there's a way to basically do that for them programmatically. Essentially create a page for them with a specific url e.g "plugin-name/fancy-page" if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: "And no, I don't want my client to have to make a page and add a shortcode." Why not? This would be the easiest way that comes to mind and make it very flexible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something along the lines of:

```
$new_page = array();
$new_page['post_title'] = 'Example Page';
$new_page['post_content'] = "Example Page - [shortcode]";
$new_page['post_status'] = 'publish';
$new_page['post_type'] = 'page';

$id = wp_insert_post( $new_page );
```